# Highchart implementation of Floating bar and stacked bar

Tags: highcharts

I'm currently working on a feature that requires to render a chart that contains both stacked bars and floating bars (see photo), scanning through the Highchart documentation it doesn't seem like it's even possible, so I just wonder if anybody has experience on doing something similar to this one

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy to create such a chart with Highcharts. You just need to use multiple series: `columnrange` and stacked `column` with specified `x` and `y` values. Please check the example below:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [...]
  }, {
    data: [...]
  }, {
    type: 'columnrange',
    data: [...]
  }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/acpk2vsb/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/column-chart